# sed, replace backslash in #include

Tags: regex, linux, bash, scripting, sed

I wish to replace all the backslashes (which appear on the same line with an include directive) with slashes.

Here's what I have until now..

```
echo '#include "..\etc\filename\yes"' | sed 's&\(#include.*\)\\&\1\/&g'
```

This works as I expect, but the problem is that it replaces only one \ at a time... If I want to replace all three in the above text, I have to run the sed command 3 times... The g flag at the end should make the replacements globally, no?

I'm using sed 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 11.10...

Comment: The `g` is global but your `.*` is greedy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the way you're matching. The `.*` is greedy, so it matches the last backslash first and then thinks it's done. Try this:

```
... | sed '/^#include/s&\\&/&g'
```

That runs the substitutions only on lines matching the first pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You want a compound command - the first pattern matches lines that start with #include, the second does your slash translation.

```
sed '/^#include/ s&\\&/&g'
```